# Postgresql - how can i create a version column with integer value?

Tags: postgresql

how can i create in a table a column with an integer value (starting by 0 when i insert a row) that will be incremented by 1 every time i update a row ?

I need it to use it as optimistic locking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use a trigger to achieve this. 
There is no automatic or built-in solution for this

```
create table some_table
(
   id serial primary key, 
   some_data text, 
   version integer not null default 0
);

create or replace function increment_version()
  returns trigger
as
$body$
begin
  new.version := new.version + 1;
  return new;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;

create trigger version_trigger
   before update on some_table
   for each row execute procedure increment_version();
```

Note that the trigger function can be used for *any* table that contains a column named `version` (that is a number).

Comment: A trigger _is_ the built-in solution :)

Comment: Can you give me an example to how to create the trigger for this operation?

Comment: Here is a complete trigger example http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single `update` statement. Your `insert` statement can save it as `0` and `update` statement increase it `1` whenever the row is updated.

```
create table orders
(
    id varchar(255) not null constraint orders_pkey primary key,
    name         varchar(255) UNIQUE,
    order_status varchar(30),
    version integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    create_time  timestamp,
    update_time  timestamp
);

-- Always save the version as 0 for inserts
INSERT INTO orders
VALUES (:id, :name, :order_status, :version, :create_time, :update_time);

-- Increase version in each update and check the version
UPDATE TABLE
SET name = :name,
    order_status = :order_status,
    update_time = :update_time,
    version = version + 1
where id = :id
  and version = :version;
```

To achieve the optimistic locking, after the update statement runs you need to check any record updated, if it is not then you understand that there is another update request that was committed before your update and you need to retry your update.

Comment: In the update I would add to the `where` clause `and version = :version` otherwise it's not really optimistic locking and you check if the row was updated by looking at how many rows was updated in the statement, 0/1.